# watir-webdriver reload when page fails to load

Tags: automation, watir-webdriver

I'm automating a process which involves loading many pages and copying form field values from those pages into other pages.

Occasionally, a page will fail to load initially, but will successfully reload.
Is there a built-in mechanism for getting watir-webdriver to do this?. Note that I'm not asking the same question as this:
[How to deal with a page which fails to load and continue testing in Watir-Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540268/how-to-deal-with-a-page-which-fails-to-load-and-continue-testing-in-watir-webdri)

In my case, I'm not trying to move on after a failure. Wrapping all my Click actions in a begin/rescue with a reload inside the rescue could work, I'm just wondering if there's a built-in solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in mechanism to do this, I usually do something like this.

Create a retriable block method that takes a block. Maybe something like:

```
require 'timeout'

def retriable(num_retries = 0, timeout = 5, &block)
  Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
    block.call
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  if num_retries <= 0
    raise e
  else
    puts "Request timed out. Trying #{num_retries} more times"
    num_retries -= 1
    retry
  end
end
```

Use it like this in your code:

```
retries = 3
timeout_before_retry = 10 # seconds
retriable(retries, timeout_before_retry) do
  browser.goto("http://google.com")
end
```